# How to set foreach jQuery JSON CSV

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, foreach

I have a jquery ajax request as follows;

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
        alert (result);
        },
});
```

The returned `result` is in JSON. To see the data, I alerted it and is as below;

```
img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg,img4.jpg
```

The php file is as;

```
<?php
$array = array("img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg","img4.jpg");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

it echos;

```
["img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg","img4.jpg"]
```

I want to alert `filename` for each file name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var filenames = result.split(',');
            for(i=0;i<filenames.length;i++)
            {
               alert(filenames[i]);
            }
       },
});
```

JSON version

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $.each(result, function(key,val){
                     alert(val);
                });
           },
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

JSON is not CSV. This should be an error. If you're receiving CSV, don't say `dataType: 'json'`, receive it as text, and parse it yourself:

```
var fields = result.split('/');
$.each(fields, function(fieldNo, field) {
  alert(field);
});
```

If it is JSON, then edit your question and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $.each(result,function(keu,value){
                alert(value);
            });
        },
});
```

Comment: working with `file1.ext,file2.ext,file3.ext` not with `result`

Comment: may your result is not file1.ext,file2.ext,file3.ext